# How Portal in Cartesi Rollups works?

Tags: python, blockchain, cartesi

I'm reading about the Portal of Cartesi Rollups (https://cartesi.io/en/docs/cartesi-rollups/components/), i understand the overview of the concept of Portal, but i want to know more about that.

When someone sends asset to the Portal, it will send info to the DApps => It means the backend will recevice a message through advanced, right? So what is the example payload of that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official [github repo for examples](https://github.com/cartesi/rollups-examples) of usage there is the [ERC-20 Deposit DApp](https://github.com/cartesi/rollups-examples/tree/main/erc20deposit), which is an specific example (written in Python) to demonstrate how to send assets to the [Portal](https://github.com/cartesi/rollups#portal) and how to handle it in the backend.